# Converting json data in dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm analyzing club participation. Getting data as json through url request. This is the json I get and load with `json_loads`:

```
df = [{"club_id":"1234", "sum_totalparticipation":227, "level":1, "idsubdatatable":1229, "segment": "club_id==1234;eventName==national%2520participation,eventName==local%2520partipation,eventName==global%2520participation", "subtable":[{"label":"national participation", "sum_events_totalevents":105,"level":2},{"label":"local participation","sum_events_totalevents":100,"level":2},{"label":"global_participation","sum_events_totalevents":22,"level":2}]}]
```

when I use json_normalize, this is how df looks:

[image: normalized data frame]

so, specific participations are aggregated and only sum is available, and I need them flatten, with global/national/local participation in separate rows.
Can you help by providing code?

Comment: Your screenshot is unreadable. Please post text as [text with formatting](/help/formatting), not as a screenshot. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Comment: I don't know to do it correctly, that's why I used this approach :(

Comment: UPDATED df as per Guillaume BEDOYA answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the details of the subtable field (which is another list of dictionaries itself), then you can do the following:

```
...
    
df = pd.DataFrame(*data)

for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'label'] = df.loc[i, 'subtable']['label']
    df.loc[i, 'sum_events_totalevents'] = df.loc[i, 'subtable']['sum_events_totalevents']
    df.loc[i, 'sublevel'] = int(df.loc[i, 'subtable']['level'])
```

Note: I purposely renamed the `level` field inside the subtable as `sublevel`, the reason is there is already a column named `level` in the dataframe, and thus avoiding name conflict

Comment: sorry, it seems that this line does not change anything. for loop gives error in line df.loc[i, 'label'] = df.loc[i, 'subtable']['label'] for not using integer. tried to wrap it in int(), however it is still error.

Answer (score -1):

The data you show us after your json.load looks quite dirty, some quotes look missing, especially after `"segment":"club_id==1234`", and the `;` separator at the beginning does not fit the keys separator inside a `dict`.

Nonetheless, let's consider the data you get is supposed to look like this (a list of dictionaries):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{"club_id":"1234", "sum_totalparticipation":227, "level":1, "idsubdatatable":1229, "segment": "club_id==1234;eventName==national%2520participation,eventName==local%2520partipation,eventName==global%2520participation",
"subtable":[{"label":"national participation", "sum_events_totalevents":105,"level":2},{"label":"local participation","sum_events_totalevents":100,"level":2},{"label":"global_participation","sum_events_totalevents":22,"level":2}]}]
```

You can see the result with rows separated by unpacking your data inside a DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(*data)
```

This is the table we get:
[image: View of the DataFrame from PyCharm]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for cleaning the data. Is it ok to update the question? df= pd.DataFrame(*data) doesn't unpack it for me. Would it be possible to have value in cell further unpacked? Out of subtable. So only i.e. local participation, and then in other column its value (100 in this case)